# Как отправить данные из формы на два сайта?

Tags: html, javascript, form, php, форма

```
Необходимо отправить данные на два сайта при помощи JavaScript или PHP
Пример кода:
<form id="forma" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="var1" value="var1"></input>
<input type="hidden" id="var2" value="var2"></input>
<input type="hidden" id="var3" value="var3"></input>
</form>
А отправить к примеру на на два урл: url1 и url2.
```

Comment: @GreyCardinal, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: спасибо, поправил

Answer (score 3):

На **cURL** вот так:

```
   $ch = curl_init();  // инициализация curl-сессии
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // для HTTPS(защищенного) соединения
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "somesite.com"); // устанавливаем сайт, куда будем отправлять POST-запрос
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);   // без заголовков...
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //возвращаем полученную информацию
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);  // POST-запрос
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "password=12345&username=Vasya");// параметры
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; En; rv:1.8.0.2) Gecko/20070306 Firefox/1.0.0.4");  // мы не робот)
   $result=curl_exec($ch); // получаем результат
```

Ну а если один из двух сайтов расположен на сервере, где выполняется PHP, на вашем сервере, то это делается классически.

[Вот список всех документированных параметров cURL`а.](http://htmlweb.ru/php/php_curl.php)

Answer (score 1):

Если оба сайта ваши (иначе зачем вам это?!), то незачем буквально "отправлять" данные формы в два пункта назначения. Вам нужно использовать общую базу данных. В зависимости от расположения сайтов это может быть просто подключение к общей базе или репликация.

Answer (score 0):

url разные вставьте на  параметр $.ajax

upd
если без ажакса, то попробуйте применить функцию CURL

Comment: можно ли это сделать без ajax?

Comment: Можно, попробуйте через CURL
1)http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/curl
2)http://www.web-junior.net/otpravka-post-zaprosov-s-pomoshhyu-php-chast-2/

Answer (score -1):

а может просто сделать промежуточный скрипт в которым две формы с одинаковыми данными уйдут на разные урлы. а основную форму к этому урлу..

Comment: А вот здесь можно поподробнее))

Comment: страничка с формой, данные из формы отправляем на action="temp.php" в этом самом temp.php полученные данные вставляем в две точно такие же формы в которых собственно action="url1" и во второй action="url2"

и останется дело за малым - отправить данные с этих форм средствами php

Comment: бред несу) без curl тут тоже не обойтись... в общем смотри ответ @Asen